# ABP Framework 8.rc.2 Multi Layers + Angular can return more claims info from Azure for Angular UI

Tags: abp-framework

I am init ABP Framework v.8.rc2 with Multi Layers + Angular and login from AzureAD. After login successfully, Angular UI is authenticated with ABP's Token.

But I need a fews data from Azure's Token like Name, Roles, Avatar ship to Angular UI. How can I do it?

Many thanks,
Bill Pham,